# Wait to execute ajax request based on response from modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, synchronous

I'd like to use the response from a modal popup to interrupt an ajax request, and then either perform it or abort it based on that response.

I've got the `beforeSend` to fire properly, but the ajax request executes anyway before I can do anything with the user input from the modal.

Ideally the ajax request wouldn't fire until a value comes back from `confirmResubmit`.

I understand that I probably need to use `ajax.abort();` to actually stop the request, but I'm not sure how to implement it in this context.

I realize that I'm asking how to get AJAX to perform synchronously... is there a way to do what I'd like to do?  Or am I on the wrong track?

```
function readyMyForm() {
  $("#my_button").submit(function(event){
    // prevent html submission
    event.preventDefault();

    // start the spinner
    spinner.spin(document.getElementById("spinner"));

    var myAjaxRequest = $.ajax({
      beforeSend: confirmResubmit(),
      dataType: "json",
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      method: $(this).attr('method'),
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      timeout: 15000
    });

    myAjaxRequest.done(function(data) {
      if (data.errors) {
        // handle rescued ruby errors
        displayErrors(data.errors);
      } else {
      updateMyPage(data);
      }
    })

    myAjaxRequest.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, data) {
      // handle AJAX errors
      displayErrors(textStatus);
    })
  });
}
```

The `beforeSend` works properly to call `confirmResubmit()`, but the AJAX request fires before I even get to the `debugger;`

```
function confirmResubmit() {
  var dataFromPage = $(document.getElementById('where-my-data-lives'))[0].dataset.dataIWant;
  if (dataFromPage != null && dataFromPage != "") {
    var confirm = $('#confirmation_modal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
    debugger;
    // do something with returned value from confirm
  };
}
```

Getting the responses out of the modal is trivial, but here's the JS for completeness

```
  $('#confirm_resubmit').click(function() {
    $('#confirmation_modal').foundation('reveal', 'close');
    true;
  });

  $('#cancel_resubmit').click(function() {
    $('#confirmation_modal').foundation('reveal', 'close');
    false;
  });
```

Comment: What is `.foundation()`?

Comment: The problem isn't that AJAX is asynchronous, the problem is that the modal window is asynchronous. The modal window library should provide a callback for when the user responds.

Comment: Then you perform the AJAX request in that callback.

Comment: For instance, if you were using jQuery UI Dialog, you provide a callback function for each button.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand your question correctly, but what if you just beginn with the ajax call _after_ you have the result of the modal popup? In your last code snippet you set event handlers for the buttons of the popup. You could call a function there which is doing the ajax call.

Comment: in answer to both - I also need to be able to execute the Ajax request without input from the modal. If dataFromPage is empty, the modal doesn't open, but the my_button request needs to fire anyway.

Comment: Okay, figured it out.  @AlvaHenrik you were pointing me in the right direction.  Solution was about getting my event handling right rather than interrupting the AJAX call.  

I moved the logic in `confirmResubmit` into `readyMyForm` and created a separate `runMyRequest` function with the actual AJAX call.  If `dataFromPage` is present, the modal pops up and the `('#confirm_resubmit')` handler calls `runMyRequest`.  Otherwise, the modal is skipped and I call `runMyRequest` in an else block.

So I end up not using `beforeSend` at all.

Comment: @Barmar [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)

Comment: @DavidRoberts You should post what you did as an answer, to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the setup that worked - passing the form attributes this way feels a little clunky, but it works.  Really ended up being about vanilla JS more than AJAX.

The answer to the question 'how do I make the AJAX request wait for a response from the user?' was not to do it.  Don't interrupt the request, don't use `beforeSend`.  Instead, only call the AJAX request after I have the response I want.

This might also be of interest to anyone trying to pass variables into a modal on popup.  For a while I was trying to figure out how to pass `formAttributes` into `'#confirmation_modal'`.  I think the answer is to target the data from inside the modal instead of trying to pass it in on the call.

```
function readyMyForm() {
  $("#my_button").submit(function(event){
    // prevent html submission
    event.preventDefault();

    var formAttributes = [$(this).attr('action'), $(this).attr('method'), $(this).serialize()]
    var dataFromPage = $(document.getElementById('where-my-data-lives'))[0].dataset.dataIWant;
    if (dataFromPage != null && dataFromPage != "") {
      var confirm = $('#confirmation_modal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
    } else {
      // submit AJAX without confirmation if no data already present
      runMyRequest(formAttributes);
    };
  });
}
```

extracted AJAX function

```
function runMyRequest(formAttributes) {
  // start the spinner
  spinner.spin(document.getElementById("spinner"));

  // form attr passed from caller
  var myAjaxRequest = $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: formAttributes[0],
    method: formAttributes[1],
    data: formAttributes[2],
    timeout: 15000
  });

  myAjaxRequest.done(function(data) {
    if (data.errors) {
      // handle rescued ruby errors
      displayErrors(data.errors);
    } else {
    updatePageData(data);
    }
  });

  myAjaxRequest.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, data) {
    // handle AJAX errors
    displayErrors(textStatus);
  });
}
```

updated handler

```
$('#confirm_resubmit').click(function() {
  // submit AJAX on confirmation
  var formAttributes = [$('#my_form_id').attr('action'), $('#my_form_id').attr('method'), $('#my_form_id').serialize()];
  $('#confirmation_modal').foundation('reveal', 'close');
  runMyRequest(formAttributes);
});
```